# A question about bounded operators on banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $L(X)$ denotes the Banach algebra of all bounded linear operators acting on a Banach space $X$. And $T$ is not invertible. Can we find a invertilbe bounded operator series $\{T_{n}\}$ such that $T_{n}\rightarrow T$, $n\rightarrow \infty$, here $T_{n}$ convergence in the operator norm.